# Can't navigate back from StackNavigator to TabNavigator React Native

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I have a TabNavigator with 5 Tabs and one of the Tab shows a screen from a StackNavigator with a BackButton because this Screen don't show the Tabs actually.

The StackNavigator is nested in the TabNavigator but where can I go back from the Screen with the backButton? Can I pass a specific route/tab to go back?

Comment: It seems your doing the logic in reverse. You should have the tabs nested in the StackNavigator.

Comment: My idea was to have a StackNavigator (Login) that navigates to a TabNavigator and the TabNavigator has several StackNavigators.